# Calling a WebMethod defined in a Publishing Page Layout

Tags: publishing-site, jquery, publishing-page, jquery-ui

I'm trying to define a WebMethod in one of my Publishing page layouts.

This WebMethod is intended to be called when a user takes a specific action in an Editor Part in a Visual Web Part, however, you can't have a WebMethod in a Server Control or User Control.  This web part will only exist on this specific page layout, so I figured the best way would be to implement the WebMethod in the page layout itself.  I would then implement a static method in the Editor Part which I would call from the WebMethod.

I implemented this concept successfully in a sample asp.net web application then set out to do it in SharePoint.  That's when the fun began :)

**Set EnablePageMethods on ScriptManager**

I started by setting the `EnablePageMethods` property of the `ScriptManager` in my master page to `true`.

**Define WebMethod in Page Layout**

In the page layout, I define the WebMethod as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void MyWebMethod(string someParams)
{
    MyEditorPart.MyWebMethod(someParams);
}
```

In the `EditorPart`, `MyWebMethod` is implemented as a simple static method:

```
public static void MyWebMethod(string someParams)
{
    // do something
}
```

I understand that being a static method in the editor part, I won't have access to any of the instance data for it.  I'm postponing dealing with that issue until I get the web method working...

**Register Scripts in EditorPanel**

In the `OnInit` event of `MyEditorPanel`, I register the script:

```
if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("myScript"))
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
        this.GetType(), 
        "myScript", 
        "the contents of my JavaScript script"
        true);
```

Background info on the script:  The script runs on the `stop` event of a jQueryUI Sortable list. It's intended to pass the ordered list (formatted) back to the web method.

**Testing**

I'm able to successfully trigger the script by taking the appropriate action in the `MyEditorPanel` server control.

I see the request in Fiddler as follows but with a 500 error:

```
http://localhost/Site/Sub-Site/Pages/default.aspx/MyWebMethod
```

Here's the error:

```
Unknown web method MyWebMethod.<br>Parameter name: methodName

[ArgumentException: Unknown web method MyWebMethod.
Parameter name: methodName]
   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceData.GetMethodData(String methodName) +841944
   System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +217
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +171
```

When I implemented this in asp.net, I could immediately hit the break point in the page.  However, in SharePoint, the WebMethod needs to be defined somewhere else.  As far as I can tell, that's the only difference between the two implementations.

How have other people approached this?

Thank you

**EDIT**

I've abandoned this approach. the necessary plumbing just doesn't seem to be there to use a WebMethod defined in a page layout or master page to communicate back to the web part or editor part.

Comment: What code behind file have you put that C# code in? Is this in a custom page layout you've created? What class did you inherit in the C# codebehind file?

Comment: James, yes the C# code is in the code behind of a custom page layout.  The class inherits from PublishingLayoutPage.  Thanks

Comment: I should also point out that absolutely nowhere else in the current implementation of the SharePoint object model uses this model at all, as I believe this is incompatible with the way the Publishing Framework works, so is probably not a supported customisation.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to use jQueryUI Sortable in an EditorPart to provide a better way to sort a set of items being displayed in the Visual Web Part.  I might have to resort to a less interactive way of doing that, e.g. a series of drop down lists...

Comment: Think you can keep the jQuery UI Sortable bit in the Editor Part, but you're gonna need a postback (to sync the web part properties to the personalisation store) to 'update' the visual web part UI.

Comment: Thanks, I went down this path because I was finding it very hard to maintain state in the Editor Part on postback. Now that I think about it, it's most likely because the markup I was applying  jQueryUI Sortable to is in a Literal, not a control such as a Drop Down List which I can enable View State on.

Comment: I have used web methods on an custom application page in SharePoint and that worked perfectly. Haven't tried out on a page layout.